# VB.NET control with the same event handlers

Tags: vb.net, class, events, methods, controls

I have this question during my project. I'm writing a program using Visual Basic with [Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express).

One of my features is a group of controls (labels to be exact). They are attached with the same event handlers (basically mouseover and mouse click). The only difference are their name and location.

Is there an easy way to write this?

I have more than 200 of these labels, and it will be a mess when I write the same event handler for all of them. Is there a class or module that I can create to summarize similar behaviour of a group control? And how do I use it?

Comment: just show us what have you tried

Comment: now I'm just hardcode everything in my program for a few label controls, they have the same events (just different name and locations ) I hope there is a way to group these controls together using only one set of event handlers to summerize, like a class or something

Comment: There are solutions for this, but telling you about it would be pretty similar to giving heroin to a cocaine addict.  Never create a UI with 200 labels.  Never expect a user to understand that a label is clickable.  Throw away what you have an start again.  Now use a ListBox or ListView or TreeView.

Comment: Im not trying to get short cut here, please do understand some of us got a deadline and requirements that CANNOT be changed, if you know how to do it pls assist, if you don't know or don't even border to answer pls do not put non-sense post to waste my time

Comment: In the Load() event of the Form you can initiate a recursive search of the controls to find all the Labels and wire them up with the AddHandler() command.

Comment: @user1452954 You seem to have left out some crucial information based on your comment to matzone's answer. What type of labels are you using and what is your application trying to accomplish. Being vague on the details is not going to help get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several techniques that may be helpful here.

First, consider adding your labels to a list. Then you may refer to them by index.

```
dim mylabels as New List(Of System.Windows.Forms.Label)

myLabels.Add(label1)
myLabels.Add(label2)
'...
myLabels.Add(label200)
```

You can also use the System.Windows.Forms.Label.Tag property to identify each label.  The snippet below shows how you can set each tag for a label on your list.

You can also associate each label with the handler in the loop, using the AddHandler command.
This means that you will not have to hardcode the "Handles labelX.Click" for each label.  I also show this in the loop.

```
For i = 0 To myLabels.Count - 1
    myLabels(i).Tag = i
    AddHandler myLabels(i).Click, AddressOf myLabelsClick
Next
```

Finally, you can code the common event handler.  Inside the handler, you can see which label click caused the handler to fire, and you can refer to your labels by index if you want.

```
Sub MyLabelsClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim lbl As System.Windows.Forms.Label = CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Label)

    Dim lblNumber As Integer = lbl.Tag

    ' Examples of things you can do

    MsgBox("You clicked Label Number: " & lblNumber)

    lbl.Enabled = False

    myLabels(21).Text = "New Text"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many samples on Stack Overflow site about this...

So just do this:

```
Sub MyLabelsClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click , ....

    Dim lbl As Label = CType(sender, Label)

    MsgBox(lbl.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case I have to refer to label1, label2 inside my sub, in that case what shall I do ?  Sorry for some policy reason I cannot show my code here

Comment: Have you try the code ? .. that lbl var will refer to any label that handled, so it could be label1 or label2 or other label ..

Comment: @user1452954 : dont forget to add control name to handles list ..

Comment: I put the exact same code on my program and try with some label, it gave me error, but If I create a new program and simply add this in it works  the error message is : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Label'.

Comment: @user1452954 : what do you working on ? it tested on VS2005 .. and could it make error **'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Label'** ? .. what kind of label you have ?